# MDX Scope Vs WIth member

Tags: mdx, cube

Using the Adventure works Cube, if I run the following code (from MS example):

```
with 
Member [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount - Range]
AS aggregate ( [Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20080430]:[Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20080502] , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] )

SELECT
{ [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount - Range] } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Product].[Category].Members } ON ROWS
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

You get the proper results.

However, when I implement similar functionality via the SCOPE command in a calculated tab:

```
scope ([Product].[Category], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]);

    this = aggregate ( [Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20080430]:[Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20080502] , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] );

end scope;
```

and then run the following mdx query:

```
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Product].[Category].Members } ON ROWS
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

I get vastly different results.  The scope appears to be ignoring the date range or ignoring the category members, i'm not sure what.  I am having a similar issue on my cube when creating a new scope with a date range.

Anyone know what's going on with the scope?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you create a separate measure, say `CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount - Range2] AS NULL`, and then use `scope ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount - Range2]);
    this = aggregate ( [Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20080430]:[Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20080502] , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] );
end scope;`?

Comment: Thats it!  I was ending up with an infinite recursion.  because the scope statement was also included in the "this" statement.  Using the dummy measure, worked.  Thanks so much!  Post that as the answer, and I'll flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount - Range2] AS NULL;

scope ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount - Range2]);
    this = aggregate ( [Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20080430]:[Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20080502] , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] );
end scope;
```

Otherwise, there might be an infinite recursion as you reference the measure inside the `scope` which you use in the `SCOPE` itself as well.